# HTML Email Status Report based on emails sent by other users

Tags: lightning, email, send-email

I've created a report based on the `HTML Email Status` report type.

I can view emails I sent, but I cannot view emails sent by other users.

What do I need to do, to view a report of emails sent by everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only the User who sent the HTML email can run a proper HTML Status report.**

- The HTML Email Status report must be generated while logged into the User account that sent the HTML Email.
- The HTML Email Status report will return no results if anyone other than the user who sent the HTML Email runs it, even if run by a System Administrator.
- The "Assigned To" and "Created by" User on the activity record itself must be the same user.

**To make the HTML Email Status report available to others**

1. Add your HTML Email Status report to a Salesforce.com Dashboard.
2. Set 'View Dashboard As' to the User that sent the email.
3. Save the dashboard.

Reference:

- [HTML Email Status report does not return records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003665&type=1)